# Fixed menu move on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I created a fixed vertical menu and fixed it using the following:

```
#main-menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Works fine on Chrome and Firefox. But on IE (11, 10, 9), the menu moves (shake) when page is scrolled.

I reproduce this issue in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4f8WA/2/

Comment: It works fine in IE 11..

Comment: @Alek But when you scroll the page, it does not shake a bit?

Comment: Nope it works fine :)

Comment: most likely you have something else in your actual page causing the jankiness. Use the UI Responsiveness tool to get a better idea what is causing the rendering issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by IE's smooth scrolling feature which is turned on for all windows 8 users of IE11. You can test it by going to Internet options, Advanced, and uncheck use smooth scrolling. And it resolves the problem. but all users of your site will not do that. So below is the resolution.

Here is a js fix.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4f8WA/11/)

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
    $('body').on("mousewheel", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var wd = event.wheelDelta;
        var csp = window.pageYOffset;
        window.scrollTo(0, csp - wd);
    });
}
```